# Importing multi-lingual categories with Magmi

Tags: magento, magmi

I am trying to create my multilingual categories with magmi. I have 1 website, 1 store and 3 store views for every language. I've noticed it isn't possible to create a different root category when a store view is selected.

Is it possible to create the same behavior as with products? => Having the same category but just different title depending on the store view selected? Or do I have to create a different category tree for each language/store view.

1)

```
+Root
 +Product Categories
  Lang1_Cat1 / Lang2_Cat1 / Lang3_Cat1 (per storeview another language)
  Lang1_Cat2 / Lang2_Cat2 / Lang3_Cat2
  Lang1_Cat3 / Lang2_Cat3 / Lang3_Cat3
```

2)

```
+Root

 +English
  +Product Categories
   Lang1_Cat1
   Lang1_Cat2
   Lang1_Cat3

 +French
  +Categories darticles
   Lang2_Cat1
   Lang2_Cat2
   Lang2_Cat3

 +Spanish 
  +Categorias de productos:
   Lang3_Cat1
   Lang3_Cat2
   Lang3_Cat3
```

And how would this translate into my import csv?
For now we have it like following:

```
"Product categories::1::0::1~Storage::1::0::1~Storage accessories::1::0::1~Tool cases::1::0::0"
```

So we use custom separators (since some off our categories has strange characters in them, just making sure we don't get any conflicts) and the category parameters and do first an update for the English version and update for the other languages.

I was hoping to use another profile, specified a different storeview (with the store column) and outputting the the categories like above but then with their corresponding translated category names.

So my question here is, do I continue like above (same category tree level, different storeviews/translations)? or do I need to create a different tree level for each language and import it as following?

```
"English::1::0::1~Product categories::1::0::1~Perel::1::0::1~Storage accessories::1::0::1~Tool cases::1::0::0"

"Spanish::1::0::1~Categorías de productos::1::0::1~Herramientas perel::1::0::1~Accesorios de almacenamiento::1::0::1~Cajas de herramientas::1::0::0"

"French::1::0::1~Catégories d'articles::1::0::1~Outillage perel::1::0::1~Accessoires de rangement::1::0::1~Valises d' outillage::1::0::0"
```

Where English, Spanish & French are my different trees.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a duplicated question on the Magento exchange: [Translate categories using magmi](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25461/translate-categories-using-magmi) I'll post the answer here so this doesn't become just another reference!

The answer got replied by dweeves (creator off Magmi):

A full category tree need to be set for each locale, with associated store view.

You need to use the [multistore syntax for category plugin](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=On_the_fly_category_creator/importer#Multiple_Store_roots_management) for defining localized categories under each root category (one per localized category tree).

So my categories column looks now like this:

```
"[English]~Product categories::1::0::1~Perel::1::0::1~Storage accessories::1::0::1~Tool cases::1::0::0"

"[Spanish]~Categorías de productos::1::0::1~Herramientas perel::1::0::1~Accesorios de almacenamiento::1::0::1~Cajas de herramientas::1::0::0"

"[French]~Catégories d'articles::1::0::1~Outillage perel::1::0::1~Accessoires de rangement::1::0::1~Valises d' outillage::1::0::0"
```

Comment: You cannot associate a category root with a store view only with a store.

Comment: PR merged with master for proper translation https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git/pull/465

Answer (score 1):

The magmi wiki describes that root categories should be placed between square brackets[] to be identified as root names. For example( from the wiki )

```
store,sku,...,categories
root,00001,....,[StoreRootName1]/level1s1;;[StoreRootName2]/level1s2
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Well this would be fine if I have all the translated content in the same file. I'm working here with a seperate file for each language. So it's not only the categories that needs to be inserted as translated.
So creating different CSV files for each languages makes it possible to set the StoreView as store column in the csv file.
I have 3 different files with some overlapping data (numerical data like stock) but with different descriptions and storeView names).
Otherwise this solution works if you want to import a product in different stores at once and not really for translations

Answer (score 1):

Since @YorichH's answer Magmi has been updated with proper translation similar to how you would translate product options.

That means that you don't have to maintain several category roots, nor do you have to assign a root (but Default) to your stores and now you can have translations on a store view basis. The syntax is:

```
Translation::1::0::1::[Default name]
```

So for example with your data. English is assumed the default so I've omitted the syntax from there. Look at the second line for Spanish:

```
~Product categories::1::0::1~Perel::1::0::1~Storage accessories::1::0::1~Tool cases::1::0::0"
~Categorías de productos::1::0::1[Product categories]~Herramientas perel::1::0::1::[Perel]~Accesorios de almacenamiento::1::0::1::[Storage accessories]~Cajas de herramientas::1::0::0::[Tool cases]
```

This will create store view translations on *the same* category root. However if you do have multiple roots that too is supported—that works as expected.

[see more](https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git/pull/465)